# How to setup network for Android Honeycomb in VirtualBox?

Tags: android, virtualbox

I have been trying to setup Android Honeycomb (3.2) with VirtualBox according to this tutorial:

http://androidspin.com/2011/01/24/howto-install-android-x86-2-2-in-virtualbox/

but using this iso instead:

http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/detail?name=android-x86-3.2-RC1-tegav2.iso&can=2&q

When I type netcfg if gives me: 127.0.0.1/8, so apparently it is not connecting in the network.

I tried setting the network to NAT and Bridge, but no results..

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

try this http://nil.uniza.sk/linux-howto/android-40-virtualbox-networking-issues

Answer (score 0):

There's no network drivers into this .iso image. May be they will be compile with the next release !?

Comment: You can try also http://ww.codase.com/. Their Android image is a pretty new one (4) and the network works !!