# no network in Android x86 on VirtualBox 4.4.2

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, virtualbox, android-x86

I created a VM based on this tutorial [How to Create an Android Emulator in Windows](http://blog.laptopmag.com/create-android-emulator) to use as android emulator for Eclipse. 
I took the latest Iso version  The Android-x86 4.4-RC1 released (kitkat-x86) from this site : [android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/)

All went fine, untill android first launch setup appears, I had to choose wifi, I put skip, and after that am stucked at a screen telling connecting but nothing happened till i get a blanc page that i have network problem (check image) [image]...

**I tried bridge adapter, i tried Nat, i tried to change the adapter type nothing works ...**

By the way, if i do ALT F1 and I type ping Mydefaultgateway the ping doesn't work when i choose nat, but it works when i use bridge adapter and here is the result of the ping :

[image: Ping Result Bridge adapter]

I read some people solving the issue by appliying some codes in console mode [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069121/no-network-in-android-x86-on-virtualbox-4-1-2) 
I don't understand what and how they solve that way, so if someone can explain to me and tell me what solution what should i type in my case and why to make me understand..

I typed netcfg commade I got the following screen :

[image]

If someone can help I will be thankfull

Comment: open VM and go.to settings-network ... enable NAT or host only adapter

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that you didn't read all i've said !! I said above that I already tried all settings in virtual box, Nat and bridge adapter etc......So your answer is not what I expect, if you have a better one please help

Comment: ah my bad .. didnt read full

Comment: it maybe disabled in network and sharing section from host OS (PC) apart from this no more ideas

Comment: Nope it's not !! I think there is something to do i mean commands to type or save in some files like others say here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069121/no-network-in-android-x86-on-virtualbox-4-1-2 
The problem is that I don't know linux so I don't understand what commands should I type ... if you have any idea ... What is weird is that No one answered my post but you, thanks for you, but it's disappointing I supposed i will get lots of help on this forum, but ...

Comment: we normally get lot of replies but sometimes its hard to get solutions :( good luck

Comment: thanks Sirnath, I don't think it's so complicated what I want because am sure that too many people knows linux android and emulator and virtualbox, so that's why i expected a help or someone trying to help, but none as it seems only you and am very thankfull

Comment: from the link it looks - edit init.sh and add 4 lines .. looks dhcp configuration and some ip address ...

Comment: Yes but needed more details on how to do  ? What ip should i fill and if its not good how to do steps back